# Remove page + query string from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have an old URL syntax and since I changed my CMS, the old syntax doesn't work anymore and I have a lot of error 404. I want to delete "article.php?p=" here :

- http://www.example.com/article.php?p=name_of_my_page

to :

- http://www.example.com/name_of_my_page

How can I totally remove the string "article.php?p=" from my URLs with htaccess please ? I tried a lot of things but it seems too difficult for me.

Answer (score 1):

To remove article.php?p= use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /article.php?p=$1 [L]
```

You can use this as an alternative:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=name_of_my_page($|&)
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /name_of_my_page?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the old URL to the new one, you must first capture the page's name from the query string with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and then use this in `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& &p=(.*?)&
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1? [R,L]
```