# Url Rewriting using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Currently i'm working on this. 
I would like to change my url from

```
http://www.demo.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id=12
```

to

```
http://www.demo.com/(value of page id)
```

Comment: I answered several of similar questions, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37701761/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15214206/1741542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for your condition please try it like this in root .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you please tell how to write the link in anchor tag?

Comment: this will work `<a href="(digit)">click</a>`

Comment: Thats works for me... But now the url looks like http;//www.demo.com/(digit)

Comment: replace `(digit)` with id no. of your post... (value of page id) whatever value you are passing.

Comment: my current  anchor tag is <a href="<?php echo $prsnl_pge_id; ?>">Click</a>

Comment: okay so it is working or giving error?

Comment: it working properly. But the url is not what i am expecting. Now it is shown as http://www.demo.com/(digit). I want the url as http;//www.demo.com/(value of digit)

Comment: what is the digit and what is the value of digit? and please run some test on this so you will sure there is not problem in coding part.

Comment: There is no problem in the coding part. But in the url I getting page id instead of page name...   The digit is 1 and it value in the databse is John

Comment: `(value of page id)` is it numeric value of a alphabetic value?

Comment: page id is a numeric value

Comment: `http://www.demo.com/12` is same as `http://www.demo.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id=12` if you are having problem in this `http://www.demo.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id=12` same problem will effect this `http://www.demo.com/12` so please check everything in place.

Comment: I want to replace the number 12 with a name John...

Comment: I've edited my answer you can use name instead of number now please check.

Comment: Now i have replaced number with name. But 404 error occured...

Comment: first check `http://www.demo.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id=john` this url is workinfg fine with name.

Comment: Redirecting works perfectly. But value didn't getting in that page. The contents displaying in that page according to that page id..

Comment: that is what i am saying the question is about rewriting now it is upto you that how you associate name with id, it is a coding part or ask separate question for this.

Comment: is there any way to convert that id to name using htaccess

Comment: you can only do for one value but dynamically you have to make changes in your php file.

Comment: okkk.  Thank you for yor support

Comment: The above code works for me. But now when i try to change url before login it automatically redirect me to index.php. Can you please suggest me a solution?